# The propriety 'setEstado' doesnt exist on type 'number | IContexto'.ts(2339)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

This is MyContext file.

```
import React, { useState , createContext, SetStateAction } from 'react'

type StateType = {
  state: number
}

interface IContexto {
  state?: StateType | null;
  setState?: React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<StateType | null>>;
}

export const PathContext = createContext<IContexto| number>( 0 ) // CRIA CONTEXTO

interface IProps{
  children?: JSX.Element|JSX.Element[];
}

const MyContext: React.FC<IProps> = ({ children }:IProps ) => { // Envolve componentes no app
const [ state, setState ] = useState<StateType | null >(null);

  return (
    <PathContext.Provider // CRIA PROVIDER com value do state global
      value={{ state, setState }  }
    >
      {children}
    </PathContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default MyContext;
```

This is Percentual file

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { PathContext } from '../contexto/MyContext'

type Tipo = {
    comissao?: number;
}

const Percentual: React.FC<Tipo> = ( props: Tipo ) => {

    // componente usa o contexto criado
    const { state, setState } = useContext(PathContext)

    function AplicaPercentual(valor: number | undefined){
        setState(valor)
    }

    return (
        <>
            { state }
            <button onClick={ ()=>{ AplicaPercentual(props.comissao) } }> { props.comissao } </button>
        </>
    )
}
export default Percentual
```

In the percentual file the state e setState which were typed on MyContext file are not reconized.
It says Property state/setState does not exist on type 'number | IContexto'.ts(2339) although typed before.

In the mycontext file i tried to type state and setState with interface and type. Later i desestructured it in the percentual file as usual. Maybe i'm not typing the right way becouse there is no specific material on google to my case to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

The `IContext` type has only `state` and `setState`, there's no a "setEstado" there.

If you wanted to access this method, then I think you should try create this method within IContext or try another type which contains setEstado ex:

```
interface IContext {
  setEstado: () => void
}
```

Comment: You can notice that there is  state, setState  in the Percentual file like in MyContext. The title was write with portuguese word but not in the files as you see in the code